# Pre-compiled Razor view to string with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

How is it possible to render a Razor view to a string, while using the new Razor pre-compilation from ASP.NET Core 1.1?

The following code is from the example and the exception will be thrown because `viewResult.View` is null.

```
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };
var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);

if (viewResult.View == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
}
```

---

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/25/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1-preview-1/

---

Old way (example): [File -> Razor -> Compile -> string](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/asp-net-core-render-view-to-string/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement an IViewRenderService and register is in your Startup.cs. Then add a function like this:

```
public class ViewRenderService : IViewRenderService
{
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly HttpContext _context;
    private readonly ICompositeViewEngine _viewEngine;
    private const string ControllerStr = "controller";

    public ViewRenderService(
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        IHttpContextAccessor accessor,
        ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine)
    {
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _context = accessor.HttpContext;
        _viewEngine = viewEngine;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
    {
        return await RenderToStringAsync(viewName, model, null);
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model, ViewDataDictionary viewDataDictionary)
    {
        var controller = string.Empty;
        viewName = viewName?.TrimStart(new char[] { '/' });
        Regex rex = new Regex(@"^(\w+)\/(.*)$");
        Match match = rex.Match(viewName);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            controller = match.Groups[1].Value;
            viewName = match.Groups[2].Value;
        }

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add(ControllerStr, controller);
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(_context, routeData, new ActionDescriptor());

        var viewResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);

        if (viewResult.View == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Searched the following locations: {string.Join(", ", viewResult.SearchedLocations)} for folder \"{controller}\" and view \"{viewName}\"");
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
        }

        var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
        {
            Model = model
        };

        if (viewDataDictionary != null)
        {
            foreach (var obj in viewDataDictionary)
            {
                viewDictionary.Add(obj);
            }
        }

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                viewResult.View,
                viewDictionary,
                new TempDataDictionary(_context, _tempDataProvider),
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );
            viewContext.RouteData = _context.GetRouteData();

            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should already work. When you call:

```
viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
```

It will find the pre-compiled view and use that one rather than compiling the view again.

Comment: Before this line of code is reached the exception is thrown.

Comment: I have the same problem, this is not the solution. As @SeriousK. says the error is thrown before that line.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50680245/1358684 and accept it as answer if it helps.